# Does the RX0 support the Sony Remote API

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

I'm hoping to develop custom software that will work with the new Sony RX0. It will require Sony Remote API support. Can anyone confirm if the Remote API supports the RX0?

Answer (score 0):

I develop an app called Camrote, whilst it seems the RX0 isn’t documented I have a user who is using it with limited success. It seems it exhibits some of the strange behaviour the 3rd gen cameras do around having to achieve focus before calling the capture image API method. I have logs from the app, you can check out any changes I make from my investigation from the commits I’ll be making to my connectivity library [rocc](https://github.com/simonmitchell/rocc)!

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately the RX0 does not support the Camera Remote API.